# Changing between Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to create a little tool that brings every 60 seconds eithe chrome, edge or "xyz" to the front.
xyz is another programm i wrote.

The problem i have is, that it's bringing me the first programm (xyz) to the front but chrome or edge is never coming to the front. Also when i put chrome as first programm to show it's not coming.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
namespace ChangeWindows
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShowWindow();
        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        private static void ShowWindow()
        {
            // Bei start ein programm in den vordergrund holen
            // BDE
            Process[] processXYZ = Process.GetProcessesByName("xyz");
            IntPtr xyz = processXYZ[0].MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(xyz);
            // 1 min warten
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            // nächstes Programm
            // msedge
            Process[] processEDGE = Process.GetProcessesByName("msedge");
            IntPtr edge = processEDGE[0].MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(msedge);
            // 1 min warten
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            // nächstes Programm
            // chrome
            Process[] processCHROME = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            IntPtr chrome = processCHROME[0].MainWindowHandle;
            SetForegroundWindow(chrome);
            // 1 min warten
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            // von vorne beginnen
            ShowWindow();

        }
    }
}
```

I'm also getting none error Message. For example like Couldn't find Process with name chrome not found.

Comment: What does the `SetForegroundWindow` return for each case?

Comment: for the "xyz" it's returning 0x001f077a. At the other ones it's 0x00000000

Comment: `var edge = Process.GetProcessesByName("msedge").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero); if (edge != null) BringWindowToTop(edge.MainWindowHandle);` -- You should also call `IsIconic()` and, in that it's true, call `SetWindowPlacement()` to restore it

Comment: When i go by GetProcessById chrome is coming to the front, but the id can change so...

Comment: @Jimi 's answer is correct
try and search for the first that is not 0x00000000
Should we post a full response?

Comment: Yes it's working. but i don't understand really what's meaned with the IsIconic() the other one. Maybe a full answer would be great :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the process for Edge is called "msedge" not just "edge"

Second, as Jimi pointed out, you should search for the first process that it's `MainWindowHandle` is not  `0x00000000`

so it should look something like this

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
namespace ChangeWindows
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ShowWindow();
        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        private static void ShowWindow()
        {
            // Bei start ein programm in den vordergrund holen
            // BDE
            Process processXYZ = Process.GetProcessesByName("xyz").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
            if (processXYZ != null)
            {
                IntPtr xyz = processXYZ.MainWindowHandle;
                SetForegroundWindow(xyz);
                // 1 min warten
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }
            // nächstes Programm
            // msedge
            Process processEDGE = Process.GetProcessesByName("msedge").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
            if (processEDGE != null)
            {
                IntPtr edge = processEDGE.MainWindowHandle;
                SetForegroundWindow(edge);
                // 1 min warten
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }
            // nächstes Programm
            // chrome
            Process processCHROME = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome").FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);
            if (processCHROME != null)
            {
                IntPtr chrome = processCHROME.MainWindowHandle;
                SetForegroundWindow(chrome);
                // 1 min warten
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }
            // von vorne beginnen
            ShowWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternativeley, for the sake of simplicity, I made my own version based on your code, in case you want it, here it is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ChangeWindows
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly string[] processesNames = { "xyz", "msedge", "chrome" };

        static void Main(string[] args) => ShowWindow(60000);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        private static void ShowWindow(int sleep)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                foreach (var processName in processesNames)
                {
                    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);

                    if (process == null)
                        continue;

                    SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                    Thread.Sleep(sleep);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```